# Moving the file name(s) into meta data

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs3

I have many thousands of JPEG files that have unique file names ( I.e. Scanned doc 1, scanned doc 2 etc. - I am sure you get the idea) I have created an cross reference between the file and the negative.  I want to move the file name into metadata in bulk to secure this information even if I then change the file name to something else.
I use PS CS3 but can't see how to do this.
Anybody know how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Inside Photoshop (doubtful)**

Photoshop (and most other Adobe products) come with an ExtendScript Toolkit, an (somewhat Adobe-flavored) javascript, that might be up for the task. In theory. See here for a dip into acessing the XMP metadata object (which reconciles back to EXIF, IPTC). [Some sample code here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1302473).

I have doubts this is a quick way. And more doubts, the massive iteration you are planning to do will be elegantly solved by this.

**Outside Photoshop (recommended)**

No way around programming. Sorry. Write a script for this. To iterate over your files and (sub)folders (I personally like php (standalone use, unrelated to web servers), others would fancy tcl, python, ruby...)

For each file you probably need to make one calls to [Phil Harvey's Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), to put the respective filename in.

Which property to use for this is an interesting question:

The XMP metadata block (which Adobe products insert) has a property named [Preserved FileName](http://forum.idimager.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=6482). [Others](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/32500423) talk of Exif Makernote for such info.

I would generally deem Exif to be more stable, if other non-Adobe tools touch these files in the following.

Comment: I agree: if you are programming it, you might as well make sure you use the most "open" metadata section/format. You are more likely to have reader support 5 or ten years down the road.